# ¿Cómo evitar que se ejecute una función de ancla cada vez que hay un cambio en el DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy haciendo un ancla a una posición específica de mi página cuando esta carga por primera vez, la situación es que cada vez que hay un cambio en el formulario (texto, selección, etc.) la página ejecuta la función de ancla nuevamente, esto provoca que se quite el *focus* de los input.

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
document.location.href = "#formClientData";

<Row className="row-inner" id="formClientData">
   #form...
</Row>
```

Probé con una función:

```
window.onload = () => { #ancla, #alert, #console.log }
```

Pero esta función no se ejecutó :c, si alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal o como se podría evitar que se ejecute más de una vez la función ancla estaría muy agradecido.